# Matlab - Generate huge, sparse, not singular and well conditioned matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have to apply the jacobi method to an huge, sparse, not singular and well conditioned matrix, but as the title suggests, I have no idea how to do generate a such matrix.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible ways to achieve that is to make random [diagonally dominant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix). It will be not singular and well conditioned.
The most tricky part of your question is `huge`. For different problems `huge` may be very different. 
For tests you can use something like that:

```
clear all;
N = 1e4; % size of matrix
percentage = 0.01; % Percentage of non-zero elements
n_non_zero = round(N^2*percentage); % Total number of non-zero elements
non_diag_rows = randi([1 N], 1,n_non_zero); % Random string numbers for non-zeroes
non_diag_columns = randi([1 N], 1,n_non_zero); % Random column numbers for non-zeroes
non_diag_values = rand(1,n_non_zero); % Random values for non-zeroes

diag_rows = 1:1:N; % Diag rows and columns
diag_values(1, 1:N) = n_non_zero; % Diag values - any large number


S = sparse(cat(2,non_diag_rows,diag_rows),cat(2,non_diag_columns,diag_rows),cat(2,non_diag_values, diag_values));
%checks for not so large matrices
% condest(S)
% det(S)
```

Here I place some non-zero values between 0 and 1 (`percentage` is the parameter to change number of non-zeros). After that, reasonably large number must be placed on main diagonal. That example is not fast nor effective, but it will make the idea clear, I hope.